# Infinite loop in useEffect making app slow down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am trying to get Routes based on a list that is coming from firebase realtime db and here is my code :

```
import { onValue, ref } from "firebase/database";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Changepassword from "./Changepassword";
import Editprofile from "./Editprofile";
import Explore from "./Explore";
import { database } from "./firebase";
import ForgotPassword from "./ForgotPassword";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";
import ViewingProfile from "./ViewingProfile";
function App() {
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState([]);
  var array1 = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    onValue(ref(database, "/users/"), (snapshot) => {
      Object.values(snapshot.val()).map((w) => {
        return array1.push(w);
      });
    });
    const newArray = array1.map((object) => object.username);
    setArray2(newArray);
  }, [array1]);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
      <Route path="/edit-profile" element={<Editprofile />} />
      <Route path="/change-password" element={<Changepassword />} />
      <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
      <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
      {array2.map((name) => {
        return (
          <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<ViewingProfile name={name} />} />
        );
      })}
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So it works fine when i run it but in the console there is a error which is repeating like per nano second and i guess that slows the app down a lot so what should i do here to resolve the error or just tell the app not to give THAT specific error?

---

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at App (http://localhost:3000/main.a26983c268266ec15e30.hot-update.js:55:78)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:105514:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:104323:5)

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you will have an error because you've set the useEffect to repeat when array1 is changed array1 is redeclared on each re-render so will the useEffect you can avoid this problem by using

```
const [array1,setArray1] = useState([])
```

Comment: here is a link to prove my point https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lamport-23i3fb?file=/src/App.js check the console each time you type, also hover over array1 you will see a warning that useEffect will go to infinite loop

Comment: Yeah, the creation of `array1` in the component would be the issue. Although I think it's also worth mentioning that having `array1` and `array2` isn't really needed, just one state value for an array should be enough, as by the looks of it, `array1` in OPs code only acts as a "temporary" placeholder for their new state which they use when calling `setArray2()` (which won't work in their code anyway since they populate the array asynchronously), whereas they really should be just doing `setArray2(Object.values(snapshot.val()))` or something similar.

Comment: yeah I see your point I was stating how it could be fixed not what's the best practice as you've stated, even as a temp variable having it in the dependencies of the useEffect is wrong

Comment: the only reason there is a array1 in the first place is because useState lists cannot be updated i guess if they can then voila problem solved

Comment: yes you can use it directly as Nick said or declare array1 as a temp but inside useEffect and remove it from the dependencies

Comment: if i remove array1 from dependencies app won't work

Comment: like it won't give me any error but Routes won't work

Comment: i guess i can update the useState list with this :                                                                           setMyArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);

Answer (score 0):

Inside your useEffect method you have onValue method which calls itself several times have you tried returning the onValue method?

```
useEffect(() => {
  return onValue() {
   ....     
 }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what your code is doing but,
Your useEffect has a dependancy of [array1]
Everytime array1 changes, it essentially does the function inside use effect which modifies array1. That modification is most likely calling use effect to run in an endless loop.
if you just put an empty array [] it will only run once. If that is not what you need then you need to change the dependancy to something that doesnt create the loop. You always need to ask the question, "When the thing inside this array changes, do I want this use effect to run?" when deciding what to put in this array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    onValue(ref(database, "/users/"), (snapshot) => {
      Object.values(snapshot.val()).map((w) => {
        return array1.push(w);
      });
    });
    const newArray = array1.map((object) => object.username);
    setArray2(newArray);
  }, [array1]) // << This dependancy is most likely creating an infinite loop.
```

Side note- the best way to tell an app not to show that error, is to fix the error lol, there is no magic hide error option, and if there potentially is, it's still better to fix the error.

Comment: While it is the dependency that is partially to blame for creating the infinite loop, the modification of `array1` within the `useEffect()` isn't contributing to it. The code within a `useEffect()` callback will only run after a render (& if the dependency array values have changed). A rerender wouldn't be triggered when modifying `array1` with `.push()`, it would only occur when setting some new state value. It is the `var array1 = [];` within the component that is causing the problems, as it's creating an array each rerender as [Zein points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74193748/5648954).

Comment: @NickParsons
It will rerender without the use of state. This example creates an endless loop.
    
    
    export default function TestComp() {
    let arr = []
    useEffect(()=>
    arr.push(1)
    ,[arr]
    )}
   
error - Line 3:7:  The 'arr' array makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 7) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback.

Comment: I [don't get an endless loop](https://jsfiddle.net/5xfLqb6a/) with that example. There is only 1 render occurring in that example (or 2 if you're running StrictMode) since there are no state values being set.

Comment: @NickParsons You are right, it is not an endless loop. It is just saying its making the dependancies change on every render. Which can be a problem as well in some circumstances.  Its early lol.

Answer (score 0):

i have changed my code to this :

```
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onValue(ref(database, "/users/"), (snapshot) => {
      Object.values(snapshot.val()).map((w) => {
        return setArray2((oldArray) => [...oldArray, w]);
      });
    });
    console.log(array2);
  }, []);
```

but the Routes only work after I change the code base, even if I add a comment the app will work

Comment: Calling `setArray2()` multiple times within a loop (ie: the `.map()`) isn't how you should be setting your state. You have the array that you want to set your state to by doing `Object.values(snapshot.val())`, so set that directly without doing an additional loop: `setArray2(Object.values(snapshot.val()))`

Comment: i tryed this but array2 when i console.log it is empty

Comment: Where do you console log `array2`? Logging it directly after calling `setArray2()` will still show an empty array. It only changes to the new value you set once React rerenders your component (which is sometime after calling `setArray2()`, but not immediatly after)

Comment: oh ok i am calling it after it is declared

Comment: hey bro thanks for staying with for this long man seriously thank you very much it is solved  